# Postgres create database is adding another schema along with public by default

Tags: postgresql, database-schema

**Postgres Level:**
Newbie

**SCENARIO**
I was going through some Postgres tutorial and playing around with the [chinook database](https://github.com/lerocha/chinook-database) and I must have done something to the `search_path` or user `role` because now whenever I type in `CREATE DATABASE` I will get 2 schemas by default `public` and `chinook`. I don't know why.

**STEPS**

```
psql> CREATE DATABASE foo;
psql> \c foo

psql (12.2, server 11.6)
You are now connected to database "foo" as user "username".

psql> \dn

  Name   |  Owner
---------+----------
 chinook | username
 public  | postgres

psql> \dt chinook.*

            List of relations
 Schema  |     Name      | Type  | Owner
---------+---------------+-------+-------
 chinook | album         | table | username
 chinook | artist        | table | username
 chinook | cars          | table | username
 chinook | color         | table | username
 chinook | commitlog     | table | username
 chinook | customer      | table | username
 chinook | employee      | table | username
 chinook | genre         | table | username
 chinook | invoice       | table | username
 chinook | invoiceline   | table | username
 chinook | mediatype     | table | username
 chinook | playlist      | table | username
 chinook | playlisttrack | table | username
 chinook | track         | table | username
```

**PROBLEM**
A brand new database results in the `chinook` schema and all it's tables being added, along with the `'public` schema.

1. I want to revert back to when `CREATE DATABASE foo` would just create the database using the `public` schema only. I do not want `chinook` schema.
2. How did I get to this situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have modified your `template1` database. From the [docs on templates](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/manage-ag-templatedbs.html):

> `CREATE DATABASE` actually works by copying an existing database. By default, it copies the standard system database named `template1`. Thus that database is the “template” from which new databases are made. If you add objects to `template1`, these objects will be copied into subsequently created user databases.

You can connect to that database and drop that schema:

```
$ psql -c "DROP SCHEMA chinook" template1
```

If you now create a new database it should no longer contain this schema.

Comment: This worked with a slight modification. I had to run the command `psql -c "DROP SCHEMA chinook CASCADE" template1` with the `CASCADE` option for my situation.

Comment: Follow up question: Can I run a similar query if I was logged into `psql`? Would I have to connect to the `template1` database in order to drop the `chinook` schema?

Comment: @alenm, yes, absolutely! Just try again :)